# Handle multiple database in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have multiple db in mongodb and one model. when user request server i want to find out from which db it is belonging. Is there any way to handle multiple databases for same model.

I want handle multiple db dynamically and also connect to collection from that particular db.
and also how to handle db connection for every request.

Comment: Do you use any ORM, like Sequelize, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can handle multiple databases with the help of Mongoose library.
You have to create a connection for the master DB which you can use to find the database name.

### Master DB connection

```
mongoose
    .connect('master database URL here', {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    })
    .then((conn) => {
      console.log("Connected to DB");
      resolve(conn);
    })
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
```

### Worker DB connection

```
const workerDb = mongoose.connection.useDb("WORKER_DB_NAME");
```

Whenever you have to perform some actions in the Worker database you have to load your model into workerDb connection(instance).
Here is the example

```
const workerUserModel = workerDb.model('users',userSchema)
```

Then you can use this workerUserModel to perform operations.
This process you can use with every database.